# Reconfigure from Raid0 to Raid1, is it possible?

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, hardware-raid, raid1, raid0

currently I have Fujitsu tx140 s1p servers, one Tower and one Rack.

They are both running with the same hardware, configures the same way, so I'll just ask one Q for both.

They have an motherboard named "FTS D3049" and is currently running RAID0 with one single 300GB HDD.
I was wonderring if it is possible to set it up running 2x300GB HDDs in RAID 1 instead?

Side note:
I can configure it though WebBIOS.
The server rund Windows Server 2008 Standard.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "[...] and is currently running RAID0 with one single 300GB HDD"? RAID0 needs at least two hard drives...

Comment: Strange, in the documentation from Siemens it says "Raid 0 configured and tested"

Comment: RAID0 shares data among two or more disks for better performance. You won't be able to do hardware RAID0 on only one disk. You could do software RAID0 on a single drive using two partitions, but this would be completely useless. So I clearly doubt you have a RAID0 on your 300GB hard drive...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels

Comment: Okay, in that case, is there any problems going from no raid to RAID 1 without losing any data?

Comment: You can buy a RAID controller and build the array from the first drive. But don't choose the wrong one, or all your data will be replaced (you have to copy your disk to the blank one, but if you copy the blank disk to your current drive, this will erase everything).